# esp8266 SD card Store date error Compilation error: 'class SDClass'

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

i'm trying to save the date, Time temperature and humidity in the SD card using ESP8266 im having this error i dont know if i have other errors
this is the error message: Compilation error: 'class SDClass' has no member named 'cardType'

```
void setup () 
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

      
    dht.begin();    
    Rtc.Begin();

      // Initialize SD card
  SD.begin(SD_CS);  
  if(!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();
  if(cardType == CARD_NONE) {
    Serial.println("No SD card attached");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
    Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
    return;    // init failed
  }
  File file = SD.open("/data.txt");
  if(!file) {
    Serial.println("File doens't exist");
    Serial.println("Creating file...");
    writeFile(SD, "/data.txt", "Date, Time, Temperature, Humidity \r\n");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("File already exists");  
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C. Please remove the C tag.

Comment: Also you haven't shown us `SDClass`. Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The esp8266 platform has its own SD library and that has function `type()` instead of `cardType()`.